# Rewrite rule .htaccess with anchor if condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, anchor, conditional-statements

I'd like to make a rewrite rule that only operates if a specific term is found in the url.

So if the `targetterm` is **target** and the url is:
`website.com/target/something/test/`

I want it to become:
`website.com/target/something/test/#anchor`

But if the url is, for instance:
`website.com/alternative/something/test/`
I want nothing to happen.

Is there maybe someone who has a clou?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(target/.*)?$ $1#anchor [L]
```

Comment: This stops my site from working. It's on an Wordpress installation so that might be an important fact?